# How to run typeScript code without a tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have written a code typeScript but when I tried executing(tsc filename.ts) it I got an error saying  "Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'". I checked for this on the net and found that the problem was because of the ES5 generators (Check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19025)).  I need to create a tsconfig.json file and include a target field in it.

I was wondering if there a way in which I could pass the generators in the command line itself and not make the tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all of the `compilerOptions` that are configurable through a `tsconfig.json` file are also available at the command line:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

In your specific example, try:

```
tsc filename.ts --target es5 --downlevelIteration --lib esnext
```

Comment: "tsc filename.ts --target es6" also worked! Thanks @Nathan